# How to add days in CurrentDate in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

How do I pass the value in my `JTextField` from my first `JFrame` and a label for the 2nd `JFrame`? Here's what I have:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling cod

                    String value=jTextField1.getText();
                    pass page=new pass(value);
                    page.setVisible(true);
        //e here:
    }
```

passing to this

```
/*
 * Passing2.java
 *
 * Created on Aug 21, 2015, 10:41:38 PM
 */

package trypo;

import java.lang.String;

public class Passing2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form Passing2 */
    public Passing2(String st)
    {
        initComponents();
        lbl.setText(st);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(131, 131, 131)
                .addComponent(lbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 116, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                .addComponent(lbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(186, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Passing2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: plz explain your question

Comment: i have a Jtextfield area in my first Frame when i click that button i need to pass the value of my textfield to another label which is my 2nd Frame the problem is i am getting error the constructor below in the new Passing2().setVisible(true); because i put String st from above constructor Passing2()

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: Is a good practice to name your classes with the first letter as Capital. Apparently by this line `pass page=new pass(value);` I imagine that you have a class named `pass`, this is entirely optional but you should call it `Pass`

Comment: Why are you not importing `javax.swing.*`?